# AttachedProperty and TypeConverter

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I would like to use a TypeConverter defined by Xamarin Forms/MAUI: ColumnDefinitionCollectionTypeConverter that allows a specific format input to define columns on a Grid.

My problem is that I want to apply it on an AttachedProperty.
Usually, it is defined on properties (Bindable Properties, ...)

I tried to apply it on the Setter part but it doesn't work:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ColumnDefinitionsProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
  "ColumnDefinitions", typeof(ColumnDefinitionCollection), typeof(PH), default(ColumnDefinitionCollection),
  propertyChanged: ColumnDefinitionsChanged);

[TypeConverter(typeof(ColumnDefinitionCollectionTypeConverter))]
public static void SetColumnDefinitions(BindableObject element, ColumnDefinitionCollection value) =>
  element.SetValue(ColumnDefinitionsProperty, value);

public static ColumnDefinitionCollection GetColumnDefinitions(BindableObject element) =>
  (ColumnDefinitionCollection)element.GetValue(ColumnDefinitionsProperty);
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Can't do it that way, because "attached" properties are not properties of the class. Add to question more detail: if you could do this, what would the *usage* of it look like? Maybe show xaml that refers to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if you want to define your ColumnDefinitions and do something else with it; or if you want to have an input that is not ColumnDefinitions to them define them.

In both cases, I'd suggest using the bindable properties [OnChanged Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#detect-property-changes) that you seem to already have defined instead of TypeConverter.

If you want to define your ColumnDefinitions and use that information to affect other fields, you can simply define a your ColumnDefinitionsChanged method as

```
static void ColumnDefinitionsChanged (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
  // Property changed implementation goes here
}
```

I seem to understand thought that you want to give a different type of input to your control that would then dictate your ColumnDefinitions. If that's the case you can contrarywise define a new custome BindableProperty "ColumnTypeProperty" let's call it, that could be the type of a custom enum of yours and change your ColumnDefinitions values pragmatically from within this new property's ColumnTypePropertyChanged event.